# How to integrate SAML with the existing application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, saml-2.0

I am new to SAML. and I got a task to integrate my existing application with SAML. I want the users to login with their user/password in my database, then single sign on towards service X where service X has support for SAML. I don't want a user to be able to sign up for a new user account to my website using the SAML support in service X. The user must already have an account in my database.
How can I implement this?
I have done a poc with the following blog
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp

But I am not sure how to integrate it with my application.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: SAML ist outdated (read the first part of the link you posted). You should read more about oAuth + OpenID Connect + JwtBearer

Comment: [I need a SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43)